# Design for selecting a class based on identifier

Tags: java, design-patterns, groovy

I have a collection of data parsers that implement a common `DataSource` interface. I want to have a parsing method with a following signature:

```
public static DataSource parseData(InputStream contents, String identifier)
```

It's supposed to take the data to be parsed and an identifier and use the appropriate DataSource implementation. Each of the DataSources is responsible for one identifier. I bet there is a more elegant way to do this than this one:

```
public static DataSource parseData(InputStream contents, String identifier) {
    if (DataSource1.respondsTo(identifier) {
        return new DataSource1(contents);
    }
    //more ifs. There likely will be about 20 of those. 
}
```

But I can't really think of anything better. Is there an appropriate design pattern to use here? Some kind of a chained list of detectors?

I'm doing this in Groovy, but Java based responses are welcome.

Comment: can't you just use a `Map<String,Class<? extends DataSource>>`?

Comment: @mck, Is there one unique `identifier` string for each concrete `DataSource` subclass, or does the `respondsTo` method have to find some sort of pattern in a potentially infinite (or at least very large) set of possible `identifier` strings?

Comment: There are up to three unique identifiers. Maybe more in the future, but certainly a manageable number.I considered using the map, but instantiating classes from a Class object always seemed a bit gross to me.

Comment: @mck, Up to three unique identifiers per subclass?

Comment: One more question, are these `identifier`strings actual *identifiers* in the Computer Science sense? That is, would the `identifier` strings all be valid as variable names?

Comment: if the unique identifiers are up to three and you have 20 concrete subclasses, how can each subclass be responsible for one identifier?

Comment: There are up to 3 identifiers by data source. So in total up to 60. I really like BalRogs answer below. I haven't considered JSON closures like this, but it's a perfect solution.

Comment: Thanks for picking me, but I must note that there is no JSON here anywhere. So your reference to "JSON closures" is confusing me.

Comment: Sorry - I meant to write groovy closures. Total typo! I'm referring to your quick generation of what are essentially object factories - really cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following `DataSource` classes:

```
interface DataSource {
    boolean respondsTo(String identifier)
}

class DataSource1 implements DataSource {
    DataSource1(InputStream is) { /* magic goes here */ }
    @Override boolean respondsTo(String identifier) { identifier in ["DS1 idX", "DS1 idY", "DS1 idZ"] }
}

class DataSource2 implements DataSource {
    DataSource2(InputStream is) { /* magic goes here */ }
    @Override boolean respondsTo(String identifier) { identifier in ["DS2 idX", "DS2 idY", "DS2 idZ"] }
}

// ...

class DataSource20 implements DataSource {
    DataSource20(InputStream is) { /* magic goes here */ }
    @Override boolean respondsTo(String identifier) { identifier in ["DS20 idX", "DS20 idY", "DS20 idZ"] }
}
```

This solution uses an `enum` to facilitate mapping each `identifier` string into a closure that generates the `DataSource`.

```
enum DataSourceEnum {
    ds1  (["DS1 idX",  "DS1 idY",  "DS1 idZ"],  { is -> new DataSource1(is) }),
    ds2  (["DS2 idX",  "DS2 idY",  "DS2 idZ"],  { is -> new DataSource2(is) }),

    // ...

    ds20 (["DS20 idX", "DS20 idY", "DS20 idZ"], { is -> new DataSource20(is) })  

    private final static Map<String, DataSourceEnum> dsMapping = [:]

    final Closure<DataSource> buildDataSource

    private DataSourceEnum(List<String> identifiers, Closure<DataSource> ctor) {
        DataSourceEnum.dsMapping += identifiers.collectEntries { id -> [(id):this] }
        this.buildDataSource = ctor
    }

    static DataSourceEnum identify(String id) { dsMapping[id] }
}
```

Now it is almost trivially easy to write the desired `parseData` method:

```
DataSource parseData(InputStream contents, String identifier) {
    DataSourceEnum.identify(identifier)?.buildDataSource(contents)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize BalRog's answer is what you want, but I couldn't resist throwing out a reflexion answer.

If you're sure of your identifiers corresponding to class names, e.g., `idX` --> `ParsersidX`, you could do something like this (disclaimer - I didn't compile this - there are surely some try/catches necessary):

```
public static DataSource parseData(InputStream contents, String identifier) {
    Class dataSourceClass = Class.forName("Parsers" + identifier);
    Constructor dataSourceConstructor = dataSourceClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.forName(InputStream));
    return dataSourceConstructor.newInstance(contents);
}
```

Finally, I saw now in the comments that it's not a one-to-one match, so this way probably won't be adequate?

Comment: Right. It's a many-to-one match, but I think your answer could be adapted to give that, you just need a way to construct the mapping.